# Flutter routes. Mobile app development

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile, navigation, flutter

I am trying to develop a mobile application on Android with Flutter and I need to navigate **from Splash Screen to Login to Main Dashboard**. Fortunately the Flutter framework makes it really easy with .pop() and push() in order to navigate. I followed this: https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/ and wrote the first part easily, I made a simple icon from where I navigate to the Registration page, and from there, being Scaffold it can easily return with "back" icon to the previous page. Ex:

```
actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton( 
              icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
              iconSize: 40.0,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new RegistrationPage())
                        );
              },
            ),
          ],
```

Besides this, my straggle or need is to implement the above scenario

- a) load the app with a Splash screen
- b) automatically navigate to the Login page
- c) after dummy login navigate to main Dashboard

--

- d) if you close the app and you are logged in (assuming I am saving
  the state of login to local database or file) then directly from
  Splash Page to Main Dashboard.

Can you help me with such implemnatation at list in a minimalistic way for me to develop further?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. That question can be considered as _too broad_. Consider reducing the scope of that question to something specific, where you tried something but failed.

Comment: hi Remi, I wished I knew how to narrow it deeper down...and in parallel I am still searching on implementation of the Flutter routes with MVC... I am starting from there. Definitely I will update the question asap if I encounter progress on my own